# Call Oracle stored procedure using Spring JPA without datasource

Tags: spring

I have the below SP:-

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE P_TEST (role_list_o OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
     BEGIN 
       OPEN role_list_o FOR SELECT id, name FROM role , role_details ; 
     END;
```

How can i call this procedure by using SPRING JPA ?

I dont want to use SimpleJdbc template as we dont have datasource configured in our module.Spring read connections from application.proprties

Comment: use [@Procedure](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/Procedure.html). Here is an example [Spring-Data-Jpa-Procedure](https://dzone.com/articles/calling-stored-procedures-from-spring-data-jpa)